# ¿Como validar con javascript el formato del string?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Quiero ver si un string tiene el formato que necesito antes de tratarlo. ¿Como puedo hacerlo?

```
var code = "45 _ygh"; //Este debe dar error
var code2= "123.122345"; //Este es correcto
```

El formato es solo números separados por un punto, primero 3 numeros y luego 6 numeros: 000.000000, la longitud debe ser 10 caracteres.

¿Hay alguna función en javascript que me compruebe esa "plantilla"?

Comment: Puedes comprobar si es un numero o no con `isNan("cadena")`. Pero esto no comprueba "plantillas" especificas como en tu caso, necesitarías una expresión regular.

Comment: Tienes que usar expresiones regulares: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Answer (score 3):

Acabo de encontrar la solución, gracias Jose. D. Jurado.

```
const userKeyRegExp = /^[0-9]{3}\.[0-9]{6}?$/;

const valid = userKeyRegExp.test('000.000000');
```

Comment: Recorda que dentro de `48hs` podes [aceptar tu propia respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) y así dar por cerrada la pregunta.